# DataEditorSupport and/or ClonableEditor using UTF-8

Tags: java, netbeans-platform, netbeans-7.1

I have a Netbeans platform program that uses a custom DataEditorSupport and a custom ClonableEditor. The files it reads are UTF-8 encoded and the editor that is created does not seem to be using UTF-8.

For example my file has

```
"TêSt"
```

and the editor displays this as

```
"TÃªStÃ"
```

How can I get the DataEditorSupport or ClonableEditor to use correctly read UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This FAQ entry](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqI18nProjectEncoding) in the NetBeans wiki might be of help. See also the [General Queries API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-queries/index.html) and, in special, the [FileEncodingQuery](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-queries/org/netbeans/api/queries/FileEncodingQuery.html).